# Writing a javascript to find sum of a series using for loop

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem in writing a javascript for finding the sum of the first 10 natural numbers. I have written the code with a while function and it is working well:

```
var total = 0, count = 1;
while (count <= 10) {
    total += count;
    count += 1;
}
console.log(total);
```

I am now wondering how you can do this using a for loop, if it is possible. Any help?

Comment: You seem to have a grasp of variable initialization/incrementing, so presumably you just need to know the syntax for `for`? MDN provides all the documentation you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Have a go and you'll probably get it about right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var total = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <=10; i ++){
     total += i;
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: i think you  mean `i<=10`, because OP want _find the sum of the first **10** natural numbers_

Comment: @Grundy doesnt 10 need to be in that calculation? 'i<=10' wont add 10 to the end.

Comment: `1..9` is nine numbers, but OP want ten, also check result of code OP and in your sample :-)

Comment: since this is a pre-test loop you will get 10 because the loop runs until it is greater that 10. This will run through the 1-9 then on iteration 10, it bumps the count up to 11 and then when the loop returns to the top it fails the test.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for loops in this case is - `reduce`.

Arrays have `reduce` method which usage looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce(function(total, number) {
  return total + number;
}, 0);
```

You pass in a function accepting a total and current number from array and return their sum.

Zero at the end is starting value.

Arrays also have `forEach` method which you can use to iterate through your array like this:

```
var sum = 0;
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(number) {
  sum += number;
});
```

PS: reduce in some languages has an alias - `fold`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant based on [lukas.pukenis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021026/2881286)

```
Array.apply(null,Array(10)) // [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]
     .map(function(_, index){
              return index+1;
          }) // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
     .reduce(function(total,curr){
                 return total+curr
             }); // 55
```

Comment: A yet-ception. THanks Grundy :)